# Play and pause to play sound

Tags: javascript, html, button, audio

Im trying to have these 4 buttons, added in code to impliment a 5th one later, but you can ignore that one atm. What I want to have it is that when I click on one button it plays a sound, but if I click on a different one, it pauses the current sound and plays the new one. I dont seem to get it working.

CODE:

```
<audio id="sound1" src="monkey.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="sounds/sound2.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound3" src=".mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound4" src=".mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound5" src=".mp3"></audio>

<button onclick="playSound1()">Sound 1</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound2()">Sound 2</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound3()">Sound 3</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound4()">Sound 4</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound5()">Sound 5</button><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
var audio1 = document.getElementById('sound1');
var audio2 = document.getElementById('sound2');
var audio3 = document.getElementById('sound3');
var audio4 = document.getElementById('sound4');
function playSound1(){
if ((audio1.paused !== true) && (audio.3paused !== true) && (audio4.paused !==){
    audio1.pause();
    audio3.pause();
    audio4.pause();
    audio2.play();
    }
else{
    audio2.play();
    }
}
function playSound2(){
if (audio2.paused !== true){
    audio2.pause();
    audio3.pause();
    audio4.pause();
    audio1.play();
    }
else{
    audio1.play();
    }
}
function playSound3(){
if (audio2.paused !== true){
    audio2.pause();
    audio1.pause();
    audio3.pause();
    audio4.play();
    }
else{
    audio4.play();
    }
}
function playSound4(){
if (audio2.paused !== true){
    audio2.pause();
    audio4.pause();
    audio1.pause();
    audio3.play();
    }
else{
    audio3.play();
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var audio1 = document.getElementById('sound1');
var audio2 = document.getElementById('sound2');
var audio3 = document.getElementById('sound3');
var audio4 = document.getElementById('sound4');

var current = "";

var playSound = function(soundNumber){
    switch(soundNumber)
      {
        case 1:
          audio1.play();
          audio2.pause();
          audio3.pause();
          audio4.pause();
          break;
        case 2:
          audio1.pause();
          audio2.play();
          audio3.pause();
          audio4.pause();
          break;
        case 3:
          audio1.pause();
          audio2.pause();
          audio3.play();
          audio4.pause();
          break;
        case 4:
          audio1.pause();
          audio2.pause();
          audio3.pause();
          audio4.play();
          break;
        default:
          var audio = document.getElementById("sound"+soundNumber);
          audio.play();
          audio1.pause();
          audio2.pause();
          audio3.pause();
          audio4.pause();
          break;
      }
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound1" src="monkey.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="sounds/sound2.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound3" src=".mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound4" src=".mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound5" src=".mp3"></audio>

<button onclick="playSound(1)">Sound 1</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound(2)">Sound 2</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound(3)">Sound 3</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound(4)">Sound 4</button><br />
<button onclick="playSound(5)">Sound 5</button><br />
```

**The button °5 should work with the default switch case. If you'll have to add buttons generically, your function will have to be changed.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with really short code use jQuery.

First. set `data-` attribute that points audio elements id

`<button data-audio="sound1">Sound 1</button>`

and then bind event.

```
$('button[data-audio]').click(function(){
    $current = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-audio'))[0];
    /* check all audio elements */
    $('audio').each(function(){
        if(this != $current)
            this.pause();
        else
            this.play();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L1gwfgcr/2/)**